# how do I count the items that turned green an show a <p> when all items are marked green?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made a checklist. Now I want to show a text when all the checkboxes are green. I don't know how can I count the checkbox. Somebody who can help me to this code?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("i").click(function() {
    $(this).css("color", "#5c8c44");
    $(this).parent().css("font-weight", "bold");
  });

  $("#reset").click(function() {
    $("i").css("color", "red");
    $("li").css("font-weight", "normal");
  });
});
```

```css
ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li i {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css">

<h2>Checklist</h2>
<ul>
  <li><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> Item 1</li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> Item 2</li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> Item 3</li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> Item 4</li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> Item 5</li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> Item 6</li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> Item 7</li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> Item 8</li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> Item 9</li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> Item 10</li>
</ul>
<button id="reset">Reset checklist</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: It would  be better if you can add a class while you turn it into green. Then you can get the elements by class name and i tag and if both the element counts are equal, you can say that all checklists are checked

Comment: Consider using a checkbox and labels to achieve this. Not only is it more semantic, it is more accessible. You also get the click to change functionality for free without JS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try here:https://jsfiddle.net/3c0uskLy/
https://jsfiddle.net/83jcvaLr/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("i").click(function() {
    $(this).css("color", "#5c8c44").addClass("grencolor")
    $(this).parent().css("font-weight", "bold");
    ChkList = $(".grencolor").length;
    $("#count1").text("").append("you've marked (" + ChkList + ")/10 boxs");
    if ($("li").length == ChkList) {
      $("#count").text("").append("you've got everything!")
    } else {
      $("#count").text("").append(" you don't have all the items")
    }
  });

  $("#reset").click(function() {
    $("#count").text("").append("0")
    $("i").removeClass("grencolor")
    $("i").css("color", "red");
    $("li").css("font-weight", "normal");
  });
});
```

```css
ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li i {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css">

<h2>Checklist</h2>
<p id=count1></p>
<ul>
  <li><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> Item 1</li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> Item 2</li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> Item 3</li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> Item 4</li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> Item 5</li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> Item 6</li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> Item 7</li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> Item 8</li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> Item 9</li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> Item 10</li>
</ul>
<p id=count></p>
<button id="reset">Reset checklist</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for converting my comment into a snippet and a fiddle as well :). Though you forgot to remove those classes on click of reset. Then your snippet would fail

Comment: Is there a option wheren i can show the value of var count?

Comment: yes you can,Use any label or span id add append it , If my answer is really helpful then upote it and check as correct ans. I just add another condition where you uncheck same one which is green also.please check it.

Comment: Thanks, i upvoted your answer! is it an option to add a count like:
<p>you've marked (count)/10 boxs</p>
if (count = 10)
 <p> you've got everything!</p>
Else 
 <p> you don't have all the items</p>

Answer (score 0):

How about keeping a counter of green buttons? For that you need to declare a variable, e.g. `var count = 0;`, then whenever a button turns green increase the counter, whenever reset is clicked, reset the count too. Then if the counter reached a certain count, do what you want to do:

```
  var count = 0;

  $("i").click(function() {
    $(this).css("color", "#5c8c44");
    $(this).parent().css("font-weight", "bold");

    count += 1;
    if(count > 5) { /*...*/ }
  });

  //...
```

Comment: thanks a lot! big help!!
Can i print the value of the count var?
for example: "you've marked (count)/10 items?"

Comment: create a string `var string = "you have marked {count}/10 items";` and replace that specific text with the count. `string.replace('{count}', count);`. Then put that string whereever you want. ie: `$('p').text(string);`

Answer (score 0):

You can count child elements of ul. I have modified your code for the desired result. You can [check here](https://codepen.io/rohit2409/pen/RmGVpE) . I have created one function for checking green color class

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("i").click(function() {
    //$(this).css("color", "#5c8c44");
    $(this).addClass('green')
    $(this).parent().css("font-weight", "bold");
    check();
  });

  $("#reset").click(function() {
    $("i").css("color", "red");
    $("li").css("font-weight", "normal");
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = '';
  });

  function check() {
    let ul_li_count = document.getElementById('ul_class').childElementCount;
    var numItems = $('.green').length;
    //console.log(numItems);
    if (numItems == ul_li_count) {
      let output = `<span> All the checkboxs are Clicked <\/span>`;
      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = output;
    }
  }


});
```

```css
ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li i {
  color: red;
}

.green {
  color: #5c8c44
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">

<h2>Checklist</h2>
<ul id="ul_class">
  <li><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> Item 1</li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> Item 2</li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> Item 3</li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> Item 4</li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> Item 5</li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> Item 6</li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> Item 7</li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> Item 8</li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> Item 9</li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> Item 10</li>
</ul>
<div id="output"></div><button id="reset">Reset checklist</button>
```